# I am having issues with nested serializers in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import UsersMan
from log.serializers import LogSerializer
from log.models import Log

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UsersMan
        fields = ("s_no","user_id","name","time_zone")

class UserLogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    #members = serializers.SerializerMethodField(source="UsersMan", read_only=True)
    activity_periods = serializers.SerializerMethodField(source="Log", read_only=True)

```
class Meta:
    model = UsersMan
    depth = 1
    fields = ("s_no", "user_id", "name", "time_zone","activity_periods",)
```

Comment: What's the question ?

Comment: It doesn't show activity periods field in the output.

Comment: WHat to do about that?